# Loading second model for page

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm new to CodeIgniter and am trying to get my head around how things are structured.

I have a homepage with this method:

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->model('header2');
  $this->load->model('homepage_model');

  $data = $this->homepage_model->HeadData();

  $this->load->view('homepage_view', $data);
}
```

If I take out the line that loads the header2 model, my page loads ok, as soon as I put that line in, I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Header2' not found in H:\Forum\system\core\Loader.php on line 303

homepage_model.php and header2.php both exist in my models directory.

My header2.php contains the following class:

```
class Head_model extends CI_Model
{
  private $data;

  public function HeaderData()
  {
    $data = array();

    $data['title'] = 'Forum main page';
    $data['heading'] = 'Welcome to yet another forum';
    $data['css_common'] = 'assets/css/common.css';
    $data['meta_desc'] = 'Forum main page';
    $data['meta_keywords'] = 'Forum Main Home';
    $data['js_jquery'] = 'js/jquery-1.8.2.js';
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrect class name. header2.php class name should look like this

```
class Header2 extends CI_Model
```

Comment: Doh! I take it the class name is required to be the same as the file name (without the extension) in CodeIgniter?

Comment: I don't know what you are up to but I hope you know that a class can have more that one functions. And you can manage both head and hearder data in one class. Also the theme of `Models` is one model per table.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with OOP (from Delphi) and have some understanding of PHP, but MVC and CodeIgniter (& their conventions) are new to me. I'm not sure what you mean by "manage both head and header data in one class"?

Comment: I meant to say, you can have `HeadData` and `HeaderData` defined in one model.